# C# mongo queries with json strings

Tags: c#, .net, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This seems so basic that I'm sure I've just overlooked a class or a method somewhere, but for the life of me, I can't find it.

I've got a json string like so:

```
{ SendId: 4, "Events.Code" : { $all : [2], $nin : [3] } }
```

I can run this in the mongo shell against a `find()` or a `count()` and get what I'm looking for.
What is the easiest way to deal with this in C#? Here's what I've found:

- The methods I'm finding are all wanting an `IMongoQuery`, which is just a marker interface
- `BsonDocument` has a nice Parse method, but it doesn't implement `IMongoQuery`
- `QueryDocument` inherits from `BsonDocument`, and it does implement `IMongoQuery`, but it does not have it's own Parse method, and I can't convert the `QueryDocument` to `BsonDocument`
- The Aggregation framework takes a `BsonDocument`[], but sometimes I just want a simple Find or Count operation
- Some of these queries are large and gross, and I don't want to build them a line a time with the `Query` builder class

If the database deals with json documents, and I can run this stuff in the shell, isn't there some way to run it through the driver?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's ugly, but you can do this by deserializing the string in to a `BsonDocument` and then wrapping in a `QueryDocument`

```
BsonDocument query = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{ SendId: 4, 'Events.Code' : { $all : [2], $nin : [3] } }");
QueryDocument queryDoc = new QueryDocument(query);
var result = collection.FindAs<TypeOfResultExpected>(queryDoc); // or just use Find
```

If it's something you plan on doing frequently, you could always wrap it in a method, or create a `JSQueryDocument` class like the following:

```
public class JSQueryDocument : QueryDocument
{
    public JSQueryDocument(string query) : base(MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(query))
    {
        // Probably better to do this as a method rather than constructor as it
        // could be hard to debug queries that are not formatted correctly
    }
}

/// ...

var result = collection.Find(new JSQueryDocument("{ SendId: 4, 'Events.Code' : { $all : [2], $nin : [3] } }"));
```

Comment: awesome! I totally missed that overload on QueryDocument because I didn't realize that BsonDocument implements IEnumerable<BsonElement>. Thanks!

Comment: BsonDocument.Parse() will be better ?!

Comment: But this will get a deserialization error if your string has a DateTime property "{update_time : " + DateTime.Now + " }"

Answer (score 13):

To add to [Shaun McCarthy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221345/885318) there's a slightly cleaner way to achieve the exact same goal using `BsonDocument.Parse` together with `QueryDocument`:

```
var json = "{ SendId: 4, 'Events.Code' : { $all : [2], $nin : [3] } }";
collection.Find(new QueryDocument(BsonDocument.Parse(json)));
```

Comment: Your answer may be shorter but it allows for fewer points of confirmation which an application layer may be dependent on to provide expected user experience or otherwise report errors.

Comment: @M.Babcock that's beside the point. The issue is that this answer uses `BsonDocument.Parse` which is the relevant API instead of `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>` which isn't really.

Comment: What is the namespace to include to be able to use the QueryDocument class ? I'm building an ASP vNext application and I can not find this class.

Comment: @Tareck117 Are you using the v2.x driver? You probably don't need that class. You can pass a BsonDocument or even just a string.

Comment: Yes I'm using the 2.0 version. I simply need to pass a string to the `Find` method ? I'm going to try that thanks.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I'm not sure what that means. If the aggregation framework accepts `BsonDocument`s then you can use `Parse` to create such objects.

Comment: QueryDocument has been removed in MongoDB.Driver 2.5.0.0. is there another way to find from a query in json format?